Disable Squid auth request in browser, but keep the automatic auth with Windows credentials
I have a Squid Proxy authenticated with Active Directory. The auth is automatic with the credentials of the user that is logged on the workstation.
But if there is a workstation that is not joined in my domain, the authentication pop-up is showed in the browser to request the user credentials.
I would like to disable only this pop-up, so that authentication only works if the user is using domain credentials on the workstation.
Is that possible??
